# Show "Direction" of Edge

Tags: edges

Is there a way to visualize the direction of an edge connecting two vertices?

For example I have two points, now I connect the points by pressing the <kbd>F</kbd> Key.
If you look in the mesh data (with a script) you see that the Edge is Stored as an Point Index Pair.
The order of the two indices is based on what point you selected first.

Is there a way to display an arrow that shows this direction? And is there an easy way two flip the direction?

Comment: As far as I know, there is not an overlay to show edge direction, nor an easy way to flip.  What would you use this information for?

Comment: @MartyFouts i would use the data to feed an astar graph (other application)